# Can a browser be used as a front end for Blender?

Tags: python, interface

We are using Blender to do some fairly simple 3D modelling - orientating STL files and doing boolian operations on them. No motion, texture mapping or other such fun stuff, just routine production work.

For this purpose we find the interface to be very cluttered and non-intuitive for people not used to working with Blender. We also want to make our tool available to our customers in a simple way.

One idea which is being proposed is to use a new custom designed GUI interface running in a browser, which then executes the required Python commands on a server running Blender.

Has anybody done anything similar to this?
I'm a bit concerned about the performance, e.g. when the user rotates the object, if t here is too much delay between moving the mouse and seeing the result in the GUI, it will be very difficult to control.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just modify the blender UI?
You can add all kinds of custom dialogs that execute python scripts behind the scenes and you can save your interface as startup-default

Comment: That's what we started to do, but then we ran into opposition from our management about having to release all our code under the copyleft license terms. As far as I understand (and I know this is a different topic), if we run the scripts etc. on an in-house server, we do not have to publish them.

Comment: you could still let the "secret" scripts run on your server, if the modified blender UI sends requests to your server and then reacts on the answer. That way, I think that you would only have to release the non-critical UI code into the open. (Please note that I am NOT an expert on GPL licensing issues, do not take this answer without about a pound of salt!)